Can every enemy be killed with a sharp throwable?
An ability you get relatively early is kinesis. Something you can do with kinesis is pick up sharp items and throw them.
So far, the only sharp items I've found are cart legs, but every time I've thrown them at an enemy, they die instantly (so far, I've only thrown them at the first kind of enemy you encounter and the little baby monsters that have tentacles coming out of their backs).
Are there any enemies that don't die in one hit to sharp throwables (excluding bosses)?
